# Web2Py insert record from list

Tags: python, database, web2py

This is my table

```
db.define_table(
'user_interests', 
Field('user_id',db.auth_user),
Field('Science','boolean'),
Field("Arts",'boolean'),
Field("BusinessEconomy",'boolean'),
Field("ComputersTechnology",'boolean')
)
```

and a list which has boolean values in it each corresponding to the value of the field in the table

```
interests = [True, False, True, True]
```

Is there a  way to insert this list directly into the table like

```
db.user_interests.insert(user_id = auth.user_id, interests)
```

How can i do it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try something like :

```
lib_interests = ["Science", "Arts", "BusinessEconomy", "ComputersTechnology"]
interests = [True, False, True, True]
data = dict(zip(lib_interests, interests))
data.update(user_id = auth.user_id)
db.user_interests.insert(**data)
```

Comment: Thank you i tried that but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. I'm working with an ajax query so i'm not even knowing the error.

Comment: Did you get an error message or a javascript error (you can check with chrome developpers tools for example) Can you show your controller code?

Comment: There are actually 12 fields in the table i've written.

Comment: Also i don't get any description of the error i'm only getting "an error occured please reload the page"

Comment: Maybe your code could be simplified a little, but this is not the purpose here. Line 65 I see a syntax error : "fieldDict[user_id]= auth.user_id)" you should remove the ")". And before "db.user_interests.insert(**fieldDict)" maybe you could try to print fieldDict to verify if each entry is correctly formatted (name and value)

Comment: Thank you so much, it was my mistake i made a typo, so i made a small change as `fieldDict = dict(zip(db.user_interests.fields[2:], field_list))`